# How to call web api Get method which i having string parameter as argument from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

web api method:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(AspNetUser))]

     public IHttpActionResult GetUserId(string userName)
        {
          AspNetUser aspnetuser = db.AspNetUsers.Find(userName);

            if (aspnetuser == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(aspnetuser);
        }
```

angularjs contoller:

```
  var promisePost = AssetService.getUserId($scope.userName);
```

Angularjs service to call webapi method:
  //Function to Get the User ID based upon UserName

```
 this.getUserId = function(userName) {
        return $http.get("/api/AssetAPI/GetUserId/" + userName);
    };
```

webapi.config:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DemoAPI",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{userName}",
                defaults: new { userName = string.Empty}
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I am getting this error: 404 not found error..please help on this thanks in advance.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:52018/api/AssetAPI/GetUserId/admin
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Comment: Does the error message provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

What's the name of the `ApiController` class? Make sure to specify the name of the controller as `AssetAPIController` to follow the necessary convention.

Besides that the routing looks fine, the code provided does work, if the name of the controller is set properly.

Comment: Thanks for your response . The API controller name is AssetAPIController only..but dont know whats the problem. And can u suggest whether i can return JSON data instead of [ResponseType(typeof(AspNetUser))]?